# How to open external drive from remote location?

Tags: server

I have an external hard drive mounted on my server running ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Server). Whenever my system restarts I click on the icon appearing within `/media/mydisk` and my external drive starts appearing in `df -h`. Before clicking, my external drive does not appear. My problem is I had to reboot my system from a remote location, therefore after rebooting, my external drive does not appear within `df -h`.

By mistake I ran `mkfs.ext4` at the partition accessible from `cat /proc/partitions`. Now i fear that my data might have got deleted. Is it true?

Also how can I access my external drive within `/media/mydisk` From a remote location without requiring to open `/media/mydisk` physically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a line in /etc/fstab you can ask the system to automatically mount your drive on boot. Then it will always be available. But if you do not want the drive to always be mounted, then you'd have to do it manually (as suggested by Radu)

To know what to enter in /etc/fstab, you can play with the manual command. That will tell you all the parameters you need.

```
/dev/something-or-other /media/mydisk       ext4   auto 0 0
```

It could also be that a line with /media/mydisk already exists in your fstab file.

PS. you can find more info about mount and fstab in the manual pages:

```
man mount
man fstab
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to mount it manually. See this Ubuntu help page to know how you can do it:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#Manually_Mounting